# Thevenin/voltage logic

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, thevenin, basic

[image: Original circuit]

So, I'm trying to find the Thévenin voltage of this circuit. I understand that the resistors (R+3R) by node a are irrelevant as there's no current running and thus no voltage drop. However, I'm a bit confused about the ones near the voltage source.

I'm currently approaching it something like: "the voltage difference between the bottom wire and the node surrounded by the 2R, 4R and R resistor is the thevenin voltage, so V_th must be what we get when going from the bottom wire to that point, adding the potentials we run into".

But using that logic I run into the problem of deciding what route to take to the node in question. Going over the 4R vs 3R+2R vs Vs+2R must yield inconsistent results, so it can't be correct. I know that when we sort of "ignore" the 3R resistor and just do a voltage division over the 2R and 4R resistor we get the correct result, but I couldn't really argue for why in any coherent way. I'd love for someone to correct my thought process here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm trying to find the Thévenin voltage of this circuit*

Just reduce the circuit in steps to focus on what you need to solve it: -

[image]

So, the Thévenin voltage will be \$\dfrac{v_s}{2}\cdot 2R||4R = \dfrac{4v_s}{6}\$

> *what I was trying to get at in my question was more the logic of why
> the first simplification is "allowed", why the 3R resistor can be
> ignored for the purpose of finding V_{ab}*

Any value for the resistor marked 3R (apart from zero ohms) doesn't affect the voltage \$v_s\$ hence, it plays no role in the evaluation of the Thévenin voltage \$V_{ab}\$ and, we can choose to remove it from the circuit without any impairment to the solution.

I mean if I handed you a two-terminal impenetrable black box that has an ideal voltage source inside, would you be able to tell that there is an internal a parallel resistor?

You would be able to tell if there was a series resistor of course.

Comment: This makes sense. However what I was trying to get at in my question was more the logic of why the first simplification is "allowed", why the 3R resistor can be ignored for the purpose of finding V_{ab}.

Comment: @iegbg well, any value for the resistor marked 3R (apart from zero ohms) doesn't affect the voltage \$v_s\$ hence, it plays no role in the evaluation of the Thévenin voltage Vab.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant concept here is that an ideal voltage source will maintain the same voltage across its terminals *no matter how much current is drawn from them*.  So you can add as many resistors as you like across the voltage source without changing the Thevenin voltage or the Thevenin resistance since the voltage source is replaced by a short circuit when calculating the Thevenin resistance. Of course in real life, adding additional load will have some effect on a real voltage source, which is what your intuition is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I'm trying to find the Thévenin voltage of this circuit. I
> understand that the resistors (R+3R) by node a are irrelevant as
> there's no current running and thus no voltage drop. However, I'm a
> bit confused about the ones near the voltage source.

Yes, the \$R\$ and \$3R\$ add to the Thevenin resistance as seen at the terminals **a** and **b**. And since there is no current to worry about, you can just delay worrying about them, for now, and add them back later on.

That said, it will help you a lot to consider the bottom node as \$0\:\text{V}\$ or ground. The resulting circuit then looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYCYtE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that \$R_1\$ doesn't really matter here. If you remove it, nothing is affected. If you add it, nothing is impacted. All it does is draw some current from \$V_s\$.

So a simplified schematic is now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqMDmx.png)</sup>

At this point, all you need to worry about is the voltage divider created by \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$. This will yield a Thevenin voltage and resistance. That Thevenin resistance will add to \$R_4\$.

The Thenenin voltage is pretty easy to work out from the divider formed by \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, also.

And then you are done! You have your Thevenin source voltage and impedance!